# Elasticearch and Spark: Updating existing entities

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

What is the correct way, when using Elasticsearch with Spark, to update existing entities?

I wanted to something like the following:

1. Get existing data as a map.
2. Create a new map, and populate it with the updated fields.
3. Persist the new map.

However, there are several issues:

1. The list of returned fields cannot contain the _id, [as it is not part of the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655030/is-it-possible-to-include-id-in-source-in-elasticsearch).
2. If, for testing, I hardcode an existing `_id` in the map of new values, the following exception is thrown:

   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest

How should the `_id` be retrieved, and how should it be passed back to Spark?

I include the following code below to better illustrate what I was trying to do:

```
JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(jsc, INDEX_NAME+"/"+TYPE_NAME, 
"?source=,field1,field2).values();

Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iter = esRDD.toLocalIterator();
List<Map<String, Object>> listToPersist = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   Map<String, Object> map = iter.next();
   // Get existing values, and do transformation logic

   Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   newMap.put("_id", ??????);
   newMap.put("field1", new_value);
   listToPersist.add(newMap);
}
JavaRDD javaRDD = jsc.parallelize(ImmutableList.copyOf(listToPersist));
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, INDEX_NAME+"/"+TYPE_NAME);
```

Ideally, I would want to update the existing map in place, rather than create a new one.

Does anyone have any example code to show, when using Spark, the correct way to update existing entities in elasticsearch?

Thanks

Comment: You can do a mapping to the ID field (EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))) as indicated in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-write

Answer (score 2):

This is how I've done it (Scala/Spark 2.3/Elastic-Hadoop v6.5).

To read (id or other metadata):

```
spark
    .read
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("es.read.metadata",true) // allow to read metadata
    .load("yourindex/yourtype")
    .select(col("_metadata._id").as("myId"),...)
```

To update particular columns in ES:

```
myDataFrame
    .select("myId","columnToUpdate")
    .saveToEs(
        "yourindex/yourtype",
        Map(
            "es.mapping.id" -> "myId",
            "es.write.operation" -> "update", // important to change operation to partial update
            "es.mapping.exclude" -> "myId"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this upsert to your Spark:

```
.config("es.write.operation", "upsert")
```

that will let you add new fields to existing documents

Answer (score 0):

According to [Elasticsearch Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html/%22Elasticsearch%20Configuration%22) you can get document metadata like _id by set read metadata option to true:

```
 .config("es.read.metadata", "true")
```

And i think you cannot use '_id' as field name.

But you can create new field with different name like:

```
 newMap.put("idfield", yourId);
```

then set name of the new field as a value for mapping id option to inform elastic that this field has the document id:

```
 .config("es.mapping.id", "idfield")
```

BTW don't forget to set write operation as update:

```
 .config("es.write.operation", "update")
```